# Qt3D compile with Qt5 failed

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm having troubles compiling Qt3D on Windows. The module compiles and links properly on my Linux machine with Qt 4.8.1. Though on Windows (Qt 5.2 personal build) g++ says `<Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h>` header is not found.

I've compiled qt3d on linux with following these steps:

1. Download a tarball of branch qt4 from [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/source/fdad0d7f39dfbc883372628fcc58c1194ab0b782%3a), extract it.
2. qmake CONFIG+=package
3. make -j4
4. sudo make install

And for Windows (Qt 5.2 gcc-4.8.1 personal build):

1. Download tarball of master branch from [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/source/d3338a9f7fcac109d7bc7f600d5974ff333782ad%3a), extract it
2. qmake
3. make // => error: missing headers

What I'm missing?

Note: ActiveState Perl is in PATH

Comment: header not found? why isn't it obvious that you don't have the header files? :)

Comment: @paulm Not so obvious... Why header is missing? I think Perl should copy API-level headers from `src` to `include/Qt3D` folder while configuring project but for some unknown reason it fails to do so.

Comment: I was being sarcastic, this question has a complete lack of detail. You haven't event said WHICH header is missing, let alone posted the failure/error from the build log, which arguments you passed etc.

Comment: Ah, that was a markup error. I just forgot to wrap `<`s in `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error - I guess its a bug as Qt3D used to build like this.  But the Qt folks are probably used to building Qt3D as [part of the modular Qt build](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#b50aae10a392d80cb2253ce34e686ae3).  My guess is that some part of the qmake step which is meant to set up the header paths is not working on Windows.

I got it to build by copying the headers manually:

```
# in git bash
mkdir Qt3D
find qt-qt3d/ -name "*.h" -exec cp \{} Qt3D/. \;
mkdir qt-qt3d/include
mv Qt3D qt-qt3d/include/.
```

Then:

```
# in VS2012 shell
set PATH=%PATH%;%HOMEPATH%\build\qt5\bin
mkdir qt3d_build
cd qt3d_build
qmake ..\qt-qt3d\qt3d.pro
nmake
```

Here Qt and qt-qt3d were in the current directory (in qt5 and qt-qt3d respectively) and Qt was built from source already.

Comment: I additionally had to copy the headers from QtQuick to a QtQuick3D folder and change some directorires in the examples to include Qt3D resp. QtQuick3D...